# NGINX with slashes after index.php

Tags: php, mysql, nginx, server

I am trying to get URLs that looks like https://my.site.com/index.php/user/login to work on nginx.

From what I understand about server blocks, nginx thinks that index.php/user/login are either a path or a directory, so it doesn't process them correctly and dies with a 404.

My server block's try file looks like this:

```
    location / {
            # First attempt to serve request as file, then
            # as directory, then fall back to displaying a 404.
            #try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
            try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php$is_args$args;
            # Enable CORS
            add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' '*' always;
            add_header 'Access-Control-Expose-Headers' 'Content-Length';
    }
```

What am I missing? All I need nginx to do is "aha! index.php is right there; my job is done", then the framework will realize that "ha! the whole URL is https://my.site.com/index.php/user/login; that means they want me to run the user controller, then load the login action" and that's it

Answer (score 0):

I use Laravel which defaults to similar rewrites (no index.php in the url)

### Here is a final structure that works well,

[Explained here](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-laravel-with-an-nginx-web-server-on-ubuntu-14-04)

```
server {
    listen 80 default_server;
    listen [::]:80 default_server ipv6only=on;

    root /var/www/laravel/public;
    index index.php index.html index.htm;

    server_name server_domain_or_IP;

    location / {
        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$query_string;
    }

    location ~ \.php$ {
        try_files $uri /index.php =404;
        fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
        fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php5-fpm.sock;
        fastcgi_index index.php;
        fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
        include fastcgi_params;
    }
}
```